# Console class is not recognized in System namespace after recent update

Tags: c#, console-application

Colleagues,
I'm having a very weird issue related to System namespace. I tend to connect it to the recent VS 2017 update, but not totally sure about that. I noticed that the simplest console application ceased to recognize System namespace for Console class, but it works for ConsoleColor?! Please see the code:

```
using System;

namespace Console
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text in your question, not a link to a screenshot of your code. When that links goes stale the question will be nonsensical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your console app is in the namespace Console, so its confusing the compiler. Change the namespace to something other than `Console` or reference it directly with `System.Console.ReadLine()` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the namespace Console. The using statements work by the namespaces. That's why your System.Console works and not just Console.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after naming my project: `MyApp.Console`.  It ended up using `Console` as namespace.  The solution was renaming the project to `MyApp.Cli`.